# Google AdWords account permissions via api

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, google-ads-api, access-levels

This question is for those who are working with Google AdWords.

In Google AdWords, we have these account permissions

[image]

Is there any way to check if a user has `read-only`, `standard` or `admin` permissions via API?
In ManagedCustomerService we have canManageClients, is this the admin? What about ready only and standard permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the CustomerUserAccess entity. It's pretty simple and example code is provided here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/managing-users

You'll need the users ID and the customer ID which I assume you already have from your question. Pass those, an Ad Client and a new role and you're good to go.

Comment: This is for Google Ads 6.0.0. Is there a way to this this for https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/release-notes/v201809 ?

Comment: I don't know. That's the old API and you tagged this post with the new API.